# android: how to have a floor-plan as image with pin?

Tags: android, image

i'm searching for a way that shows a floor-plan (png) for an exhibition in android and shows where a booth is located (for example with a pin). 
any suggestions?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you intend to show a floor-plan image map which is local to your phone or downloaded from url.

Answer (score 2):

The code for Google IO's scheduler has a great example of this.

https://github.com/google/iosched

Enjoy :]

Comment: thanks! this is a lot of code. i think i need days to figure out how this really works:)

Comment: Well you only really need to look at the Map portion of the code, but its still a lot of code to play with.  I refer to this example frequently.  Have fun :]

Comment: @bebe but it is not using a local png file (downloaded from url or located in the sdcard). Could you share us other samples?

Comment: Can't believe the code for I/O is public! This is a gold mine, I've been trying to replicate this for weeks now...

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.